# Scala+Linux: Cannot find main class for jar

Tags: linux, scala

I have a simple scala program:

**`main.scala`**:

```scala
object Program {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

It compiles just fine:

```
$ scalac -nowarn -d bin/scala.jar code/main.scala
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
$ scala bin/scala.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find main class for jar: bin/scala.jar
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$$anonfun$runTarget$1$1.apply(MainGenericRunner.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$$anonfun$runTarget$1$1.apply(MainGenericRunner.scala:62)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

If I follow this same procedure on Windows, the program executes just fine. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala can't find the main class because `scala.jar` is not on the classpath which contains `Program`. Run it with `scala -cp scala.jar Program` to set up the classpath and call the main in Program.

Comment: Thanks Brian. When I am in the directory with `scala.jar`, and run `scala Program`, it says `Cannot figure out how to run target: Program`. Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Does `scala.jar` contain the class file for `Program`? If so, try `scala -cp scala.jar Program` to load `scala.jar` into the classpath.

Comment: That worked! Would you update the answer for future generations to benefit from this knowledge?